# Combining SQL CASE Expressions In User Defined Form

Tags: sql, oracle, case, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create some user defined forms in our ERP system with an Oracle Database. I have run into an issue where a lower level query cannot pull from an upper level field since that field is populated from a query.

My question here is; Is it possible to combine these two statements?

First query:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(V, '999,999,999.00')
WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(V1, '999,999,999.00')
ELSE ' '
END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

This query pulls in the correct data and feeds field G, but causes the below query to error out.

Also, without converting TO_CHAR in the above statement, I receive the error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR" is there another way around this?

Latter query:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN E = 0 THEN 1 
ELSE ROUND(((G+H+I) / J),2)
END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

I have tried this but am getting error "ORA-00905: missing keyword"

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN E = 0 THEN 1 
ELSE CASE WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(((V+H+I)/J), '999,999,999.00')
WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(((V1+H+I)/J), '999,999,999.00')
END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

I am ultimately trying to create the first CASE expression for all fields (G,H,I,J) in the 2nd query.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Case _expressions_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the *branches* of a `case` statement must return the same data type. 
 
So in this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(V, '999,999,999.00')
WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(V1, '999,999,999.00')
ELSE ' '
END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

if you remove `TO_CHAR` then you get an error because the ELSE *branch* returns a string. 
 **If** you want to return `0` instead of `' '` you can do this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN V
WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN V1
ELSE 0
END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

In the last of your queries:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN E = 0 THEN 1 
  ELSE 
    CASE 
      WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(((V+H+I)/J), '999,999,999.00')
      WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN TO_CHAR(((V1+H+I)/J), '999,999,999.00')
    END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

you have a nested `case` inside another `case` and you forgot the last `end`.
Also the data types returned are different from the 2 branches. 
Maybe change to this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN E = 0 THEN 1 
    ELSE 
      CASE 
        WHEN VV = 'Y' AND V11 IS NULL OR V11 = 'N' THEN (V+H+I)/J
        WHEN V11 = 'Y' AND VV IS NULL OR VV = 'N' THEN (V1+H+I)/J
      END
  END
FROM V_UD_TOOL_RFQ 
WHERE PARENT_ID = :ID
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me!